# What's the best library for testing React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs

Hello I was using jest and enzyme for testing React, and now we added some hooks for the project and we were wondering what will be the possible options for the library to test React Hooks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`react-testing-library` is a very light-weight solution for testing React components. It extends upon react-dom and react-dom/test-utils to provide light utility functions. It encourages you to write tests that closely resemble how your react components are used.

https://blog.logrocket.com/a-quick-guide-to-testing-react-hooks-fa584c415407/

Follow this blog for more info on testing hooks using `react-testing-library`

Also `react-hooks-testing-library` [this](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/) seems to be another nice option